# How long does it take for an account merge request to be processed?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, merge-accounts

Before anyone gets the wrong idea, **I am not at all complaining**. I could not find an ETA on the contact us page or from briefly scraping google and meta SO. What is the estimated time required for SO administration to process an account merge request? Is there a time period where both of my accounts become disabled and I should not be logged in navigating SO?

I submitted my request a couple of hours ago using the contact page on SO. I wanted to merge [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1128266/jacob-pollack) account onto my current StackExchange profile that I am posting on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One account is simply merged into the other, so you don't have to stop using the site.

And there is no guaranteed reply time. About 24 hours is probably a reasonable assumption. Remember that these requests have to be processed by real people, most of whom are located in the U.S. and sleep while the rest of the world is awake.